# Swift delegate protocol in framework used in ObjC

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks, delegates, protocols

I have a problem with a delegate protocol I wrote in swift 3.2 code, included in a framework then included in an ObjC app.
This was the initial code

**MyDelegate.swift**

```
public protocol MyDelegate : class {
    func viewDidClose(_ view: MyView)
    func viewDidFail(_ view: MyView, error: MyError)
}
```

**MyView.swift**

```
import UIKit

public class MyView: UIView {
    weak open var delegate: MyDelegate?
    ...
}

public enum MyError: Error, LocalizedError {
    case noError
    case error1
    case error2

    public var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .noError:
            return "No error occurred"
        case .error1:
            return "Error 1"
        case .error2:
            return "Error 2"
    }
}
```

Including this code in a framework the resulting Module-Swift.h automatic-generated header didn't include either the delegate property, the protocol and the error.

According to some suggestions, I added `@objc` in the protocol declaration, in the Error enum and I added `Int` as the first type like this

```
@objc public protocol MyDelegate : class {
...
}

@objc public enum MyError: Int, Error, LocalizedError {
...
}
```

Now the framework header is correctly presenting the delegate property, the delegate protocol definition and the MyError declaration as follow

**MyView-Swift.h**

```
...

@protocol MyDelegate;
@class NSCoder;

SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC12MyView12MyView")
@interface MyView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyDelegate> _Nullable delegate;
...
@end

@interface MyView (SWIFT_EXTENSION(MyView))
@end

enum MyError : NSInteger;

SWIFT_PROTOCOL("_TtP12MyView20MyDelegate_")
@protocol MyDelegate
- (void)viewDidClose:(MyView * _Nonnull)myView;
- (void)viewDidFail:(MyView * _Nonnull)myView error:(enum MyError)error;
@end

typedef SWIFT_ENUM(NSInteger, MyError) {
    MyErrorNoError = 0,
    MyError1 = 1,
    MyError2 = 2
};
static NSString * _Nonnull const MyErrorDomain = @"MyView.MyError";

@interface UIDevice (SWIFT_EXTENSION(MyView))
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString * _Nonnull identifier;
@end
```

In a swift test project all is still working fine.

In the ObjC app using the framework all is working (I can instantiate and use MyView as expected) but when I set the delegate property using

```
@import MyView;
...
self.myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
self.myView.delegate = self;
```

the app crashes at runtime (it compiles without any problem)

```
-[MyView.MyView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9d82d2fc10
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyView.MyView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9d82d2fc10'
```

I cannot figure out what is the reason for this issue

**UPDATE: Solved**

I found the solution passing by the swift 4 automatic code update.
I only needed to add `@bjc` on the delegate property on the **MyView.swift** file

```
@objc weak open var delegate: MyDelegate?
```

Comment: Provide the declaration for self, while setting the delegate.

Comment: I updated the question, I found the problem